# Why is PowerShell telling me a String is not a String? And only when calling String.Length, first

Tags: powershell

I'm setting an XML attribute with a String, and PowerShell tells me "only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties".  Here's a simple example.  First, I run this:

```
$xmlDoc = [xml]@"
<root>
  <ComponentRef Id="a" />
</root>
"@

$newId = "b"

$length = $newId.Length

Write-Host ("`n`$newId is a string, see: `$newId.GetType().FullName = " + $newId.GetType().FullName + "`n")
Write-Host ("Running `"`$xmlDoc.root.ComponentRef.Id = `$newId`"...`n")
$xmlDoc.root.ComponentRef.Id = $newId
Write-Host ("ComponentRef.Id is now: " + $xmlDoc.root.ComponentRef.Id)
```

For me, the output is:

```
$newId is a string, see: $newId.GetType().FullName = System.String

Running "$xmlDoc.root.ComponentRef.Id = $newId"...

Cannot set "Id" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties.
At D:\Build\Tools\mass processing\Untitled4.ps1:14 char:27
+ $xmlDoc.root.ComponentRef. <<<< Id = $newId
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

ComponentRef.Id is now: a
```

That error message has got to be wrong. The value on the right side of the equals sign *is* a String, as shown in the output above.  But it errored, so the XML attribute still reads "a".  Now it gets weirder.  Let's comment out the line that calls $newId.length, and watch it work correctly.

Commenting out as such: `#$length = $newId.Length`. The output is now:

```
$newId is a string, see: $newId.GetType().FullName = System.String

Running "$xmlDoc.root.ComponentRef.Id = $newId"...

ComponentRef.Id is now: b
```

I'm not asking for a fix, because I know how to work around this issue by casting to [string] on the right side of the last assignment operator.  What I'd like to know is:

Can anyone explain why calling $newId.Length (a getter!) could cause PowerShell to think $newId is no longer a string?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems the problem is somewhere in how PowerShell objects are adapted from the root .NET objects (for example, in C# you couldn't call xmlDoc.root -- root is a property that PS is adding). This should be transparent to PS and to any .NET objects you encounter, so I'm not sure why this one is blowing up. $xmlDoc.root.ComponentRef.SetAttribute("Id", $newId) for instance works fine. Very weird...

Comment: It's gotta be something like that.  It's sure weird that calling Length would trigger it.  Makes me think it's a PowerShell bug.  Maybe that's as far as the answer will go, we'll see ;)  I'm not sure if the PowerShell team takes bug reports from the general public or not.

Comment: JohnB they do take bug reports - login to connect.microsoft.com/powershell with a live id and log the bug with the repro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an unfortunate bug in the V2 extended type system where a `psobject` wrapper can get created around a base .NET Type.  This can happen when you add members to an object or when you access a property that doesn't exist.  It can also happen when you access the `psobject` property on an object IIRC e.g. `$newId.psobject`.  When you stay within PowerShell this usually doesn't cause any problems.

Update: This isn't a problem calling out to .NET. Some quick .NET test code shows that it gets an unwrapped object for a property setter.  After looking at this with `Trace-Command` it appears to be a bug in PowerShell's `XmlNodeAdapater`:

```
DEBUG: ETS Information: 0 :  Method      Enter PSObject..ctor():object = System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException:
 Cannot set "Id" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties. --->
System.Management.Automation.SetValueException: Cannot set "Id" because only strings can be used as values to set
XmlNode properties.
   at System.Management.Automation.XmlNodeAdapter.PropertySet(PSProperty property, Object setValue, Boolean
convertIfPossible)
   at System.Management.Automation.Adapter.BasePropertySet(PSProperty property, Object setValue, Boolean convert)
   at System.Management.Automation.PSProperty.SetAdaptedValue(Object setValue, Boolean shouldConvert)
   at System.Management.Automation.PSProperty.set_Value(Object value)
   at System.Management.Automation.PropertyReferenceNode.SetValue(PSObject obj, Object property, Object value,
ExecutionContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.PropertyReferenceNode.SetValue(PSObject obj, Object property, Object value,
ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.AssignablePropertyReference.SetValue(Object value, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.AssignmentStatementNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ExecutionContext
context)
   at System.Management.Automation.StatementListNode.ExecuteStatement(ParseTreeNode statement, Array input, Pipe
outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context)
```

One way to ensure you always get the `base` .NET object is:

```
$xmlDoc.root.ComponentRef.Id = $newId.psobject.baseobject
```

Good news is that this issue is fixed in V3 e.g.:

```
PS> $xmlDoc = [xml]@"
<root>
  <ComponentRef Id="a" />
</root>
"@

PS> $newId = "b"

PS> $newId.Length
1

PS> $newId.psobject.typenames
System.String
System.Object

PS> $xmlDoc.root.ComponentRef.Id = $newId

PS> $xmlDoc | format-xml # From PowerShell Community Extensions
<root>
  <ComponentRef Id="b" />
</root>
```

Comment: Makes sense that the XML adapter is causing the issue. That would explain why falling back on the .NET method SetAttribute works: $xmlDoc.root.ComponentRef.SetAttribute("Id", $newId)

Comment: I have the same problem in 5.0 (windows 10). It seems that this "feature" is popping up again...

Comment: The OP's script works for me on 5.0 build 5.0.10130.0.  Which build of 5.0 are you running?

Comment: I'm getting this in Server 2016 (v5.1.14300.1000). I think it's something to do with how you access the variable interactively before assigning, because a restart of the shell and re-run the script made it go way. I had been experimenting with commands interactively prior to that. No amount of casting or .ToString() effort seemed to work.