# How to change the value of XML Element attribute using PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to access and change the particular attribute from XML tag

XML:

```
<office>
  <staff branch="Hanover" Type="sales">
    <employee>
        <Name>Tobias Weltner</Name>
        <function>management</function>
        <age>39</age>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <Name>Cofi Heidecke</Name>
        <function>security</function>
        <age>4</age>
    </employee>
  </staff>
  <staff branch="London" Type="Technology">
   <employee>
    <Name>XXXX</Name>
    <function>gement</function>
    <age>39</age>
```

From the above example I want to print  branch attribute and then want to change it with one value such as New York in all the whole XML and using below code to do that

```
       $xml=New-Object XML

      $xml.Load("C:\FE6Work.xml")

      $node=$xml.SelectNodes("/office/staff")

      write-output $node.branch
      $node.branch="New York"
```

But get an error stating can't find the element.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update the value for a XML node using PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202567/how-can-i-update-the-value-for-a-xml-node-using-powershell)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("/office/staff");
foreach($node in $nodes) {
    $node.SetAttribute("branch", "New York");
}
```

This will iterate through all nodes returned by SelectNodes() and modify each one.

Comment: @user3759904: Did you type it as 'setAttribute' or 'SetAttribute' (it should be the latter, it's case-sensitive)?. If you did type it with the correct casing, what happens exactly (e.g. you get an error or the attribute doesn't change)?

Comment: Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.XPathNodeList] doesn't contain a method named 'SetAttribute'.

Comment: @user3759904: You're probably using a different PowerShell version, I have tested with 4.0 and it works flawlessly using your code and input. In any case, I have edited my answer with a longer version, that should work in earlier PowerShell versions as well.

Comment: ok thanks for quick reply. One more thing. I am trying to access first three chrachter from the branch atttribute value using below code

 $foldername=$xml.Office.Staff | Select branch | Substring(2)

getting below error
The term 'Substring' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again

Comment: I've got powershell 2.0 :(

Comment: `$foldername = $xml.Office.Staff | Select-Object { $_.branch.Substring(0, 3) }` should work in any PowerShell version I think.

Comment: Thanks last thing I am trying to concatinate the output
       $folders=$xml.office.staff |  = 'PROD_' + Select-Object { $_.branch.Substring(2)}

getting below error
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '+' operator.
At line:17 char:54

Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:17 char:56

Unexpected token 'Select-Object' in expression or statement.
At line:17 char:56

Comment: @user3759904: Your concatenation should go in the script block, e.g. `$foldername = $xml.Office.Staff | Select-Object { "PROD_" + $_.branch.Substring(0, 3) }`.

Comment: is there any alternative of SetAttribute as I dont think so upgrade would be an option for me, as I want to set the new concat value to the attribute branch

Comment: You should be able to use the code in my edited answer (the edit I made 45 mins ago) even in earlier PowerShell versions. Did you try that? It does not use SetAttribute(), but a simple `foreach` loop to iterate through the elements.

Comment: Cannot set "branch" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties.

Comment: I did try  $node.branch = '"' + $folders + '"'; ending its written &quote; &quote; in a file

Comment: Ok, this appears to be a PowerShell 2.0 bug as per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355578/why-is-powershell-telling-me-a-string-is-not-a-string-and-only-when-calling-str. I've edited my answer once again to use SetAttribute(). This should work, because it will be applied on individual nodes and SetAttribute() goes back a long way. You won't be needing the double-double quotes.

Comment: thanks for your help on this, getting an error on xml.Save($path) any idea on this would be very helpful

Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Save" and the argument count: "1".

Comment: that is sorted but its writting a blank value in XML attribute

Comment: $folders=$xml.office.Staff | Select-Object{ $FolderNameInitial + $_.branch.Substring(4)}
  $nodes=$xml.SelectNodes("/office/staff")
  foreach($node in $nodes) {
     if($node -eq $null)
    {
    write-output "Atrribute/Property not found"
    }
    else
    {
    $node.SetAttribute("branch",$folders)
        }
     
}
   $xml.Save($path)

Comment: Ok, you mixed up two different approaches here and this is also way out of the scope of the original question. Here's a semi-complete script that replaces the "branch" attribute with "PROD_" + the first 3 characters of the branch name. `$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("/office/staff")
foreach($node in $nodes)
{
    $folders = "PROD_" + $node.branch.Substring(0, 3)
    $node.SetAttribute("branch", $folders);
}`

Comment: You are superstar...Thanks for your help dude

Comment: Dude, this is awesome!  I wrote this big fancy UI and thought I'd have to scrap the whole thing, because I couldn't figure out how to change XML values.  +1, awesome, you rock.

Comment: @PeterK, I can't edit your post (too short edit), branch string is missing double quotes at the end.

Comment: @LeFlou: Thank you, I have added the missing double quote.

Answer (score 13):

You can access the attributes directly in the `[xml]` object like this:

```
# C:\temp> $xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\FE6Work.xml)
# C:\temp> $xml.office.staff

branch                   Type                           employee                                                             
------                   ----                           --------                                                             
Hanover                  sales                          {Tobias Weltner, Cofi Heidecke}                                      
London                   Technology                     {XXXX, Cofi}                                                         

# C:\temp> $xml.office.staff | foreach{$_.branch = "New York"}
# C:\temp> $xml.office.staff

branch                   Type                           employee                                                             
------                   ----                           --------                                                             
New York                 sales                          {Tobias Weltner, Cofi Heidecke}                                      
New York                 Technology                     {XXXX, Cofi}
```

Comment: thanks for your help on this, getting a below error on xml.Save($path) any idea on this would be very helpful

Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Save" and the argument count: "1".

Comment: Ignore that its sorted

Comment: when i am updating file its writing blank values in the xml such as branch set to " " updated code is 


  $folders=$xml.office.Staff | Select-Object{ $FolderNameInitial + $_.branch.Substring(4)}
  $nodes=$xml.SelectNodes("/office/staff")
  foreach($node in $nodes) {
     if($node -eq $null)
    {
    write-output "Atrribute/Property not found"
    }
    else
    {
    $node.SetAttribute("branch",$folders)
        }
     
}
   $xml.Save($path)

Answer (score 4):

if we are taking attribute from console and changing its value ?

```
$path=Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter path of xml file'
[xml]$xmldata = get-content "$path"

$tag = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter tag'
$value = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter value'
$xmldata.InstallConfig.$tag="$value"
$xmldata.Save($path)
```