# Replace content of an XML based on a lookup table in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have an XML file with some specific keywords I need to replace, here's an example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Exported at 23-09-2019 10:01:23-->
<DEFTABLE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Folder.xsd">
    <SMART_FOLDER JOBISN="1" APPLICATION="6261" SUB_APPLICATION="R001J_CMNOK" JOBNAME="6261_R001J_CMNOK" DESCRIPTION="Snapshot des jobs not ok de control-m ds intraprd2" >
        <JOB JOBISN="2" APPLICATION="6261" SUB_APPLICATION="R001J_CMNOK" MEMNAME="R010J.BAT" JOBNAME="6261R001J010J_CMNOK" DESCRIPTION="[07:00] Chargement job ended_notok" CREATED_BY="Graf">
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%LIBMEMSYM" VALUE="%%VG_LIBMEMSYM./CTM.var" />
            <RULE_BASED_CALENDARS NAME="*" />
        </JOB>
        </SMART_FOLDER>
</DEFTABLE>
```

I need to replace "Recette" with "Production" and "6261_R001J_CMNOK" with "6261_P001J_CMNOK" and write the new XML in a copy of the file I made earlier like this:

```bsh
$CreateFileName = $($OriginalXMLFilePath -replace ".{4}$") + "_" + $(Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S") + ".xml"
$CopyFile = Copy-Item $OriginalXMLFilePath -Destination $CreateFileName -Force
# New file name is 6261_XML_2019-11-18_135100.xml
```

I made the following variables:

```bsh
$A_Lookup = @("Recette","6261_R001J_CMNOK")
$B_Replace = @("Production", "6261_P001J_CMNOK")
```

Here was the rest of my code to replace the XML:

```bsh
$Read = Get-Content -Path $OriginalXMLFilePath
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $A_Lookup.length; $i++) {
    $Read = $Read -replace $A_Lookup[$i], $B_Replace[$i]
}
Remove-Item -Path $OriginalXMLFilePath -Force 
Add-Content -Path $OriginalXMLFilePath -Value $Read -Force
```

Problem is, there was around 25+ items after the `@(` and that's not very optimized when we need to add more content there. So I decided to make a lookup table instead:

```bsh
$lookupTable = @{
    "Recette" = "Production"
    "6261_R001J_CMNOK" = "6261_P001J_CMNOK"
}
```

But now my main issue is that the part of my code that would replace `$A_Lookup` by `$B_Replace` doesn't work anymore. I tried the "Solution 4" on [this page](https://config9.com/windows/powershell/how-to-replace-multiple-strings-in-a-file-using-powershell/) and other solutions around Stack Overflow but none really worked for me. What's blocking me the most is that I can't seem to write anything into the new XML file.

I'm running on the latest version of PowerShell.

Comment: Do not use string replacements for operations like that. Read the file into an XML object and use XPath expressions for selecting the attribute whose value you want to replace.

Comment: Generally, I would **not** use text replacements on an XML file but tread an `XML` document as an `XML` document, see e.g. [How to change the value of XML Element attribute using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24679454/1701026), or more common: [Calling XMLDocument Methods in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/calling-xmldocument-methods-in-powershell/)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thank you for your answer, i'm a beginner so i have to idea how to do that. Is that what you meant ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-6

Comment: `Select-Xml` is best suited for reading data from XML, but you want to modify nodes, so you should use the XML objects' `SelectNodes()` method (see the first link iRon posted, or do a search for [xml] and selectnodes here on SO).

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, i'll try using this and report back !

Comment: Can you perhaps show the actual XML? `<APPLICATION="6261" DATACENTER="Recette" FOLDER_NAME="6261_R001J_CMNOK">` is not valid XML

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i added the full XML to my post.

Comment: So my issue with the SelectNodes() method is that, i can have many nodes i need to replace with the same text (ex. : APPLICATION="RECETTE" and DATACENTER="RECETTE", etc) so that's why i used the string replacement method, so i don't have to write every single node in my huge XML

Comment: Basic algorithm: loop over the keys of your hashtable, select the nodes matching the key, loop over the selected nodes, replace the key with the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

You can break down your task as follows:

- Discover all XML nodes with attributes
- For each such node:

  - Inspect the value of each attribute
  - If the current value exists as a key in your lookup table, replace it

```bsh
$LookupTable = @{
  "Recette" = "Production"
  "6261_R001J_CMNOK" = "6261_P001J_CMNOK"
}

$Document = [xml](Get-Content -Path $OriginalXMLFilePath)

# Let's find all nodes that have any attributes
$NodeList = $Document |Select-Xml -XPath '//*[@*]'

# iterate over the nodes, and replace all relevant attribute values
foreach($Node in $NodeList.Node) {
  foreach($Attribute in $Node.Attributes) {
    if($LookupTable.ContainsKey($Attribute.Value)){
      $Attribute.Value = $LookupTable[$Attribute.Value]
    }
  }
}

# save the document
$CreateFileName = $($OriginalXMLFilePath -replace ".{4}$") + "_" + $(Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S") + ".xml"
$Document.Save((Resolve-Path $CreateFileName).ProviderPath)
```